# MongoDB - sort by words

Tags: mongodb

Having data like below.

```
{
    "summary": "testing api1",
    "UpdatedDate": {
        "$date": "2018-12-30T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "status": "draft"
},
{
    "summary": "testing api2",
    "UpdatedDate": {
        "$date": "2018-12-30T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "status": "published"
},
{
    "summary": "testing api3",
    "UpdatedDate": {
        "$date": "2018-12-30T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "status": "delete"
}
```

I want to sort based "**status**" 
For ex: If I have given sort by status "**published**" then I need data like below

```
{
    "summary": "testing api2",
    "UpdatedDate": {
        "$date": "2018-12-31T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "status": "published"
},
{
    "summary": "testing api1",
    "UpdatedDate": {
        "$date": "2018-12-30T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "status": "draft"
},
{
    "summary": "testing api3",
    "UpdatedDate": {
        "$date": "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "status": "delete"
}
```

It's possible in mongodb? or anything available similar like this?

Comment: I think you should use `$sort` with `$meta` for getting the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you would assign a numerical value. But you can do it just as you have it with Aggregation framework.

Something like this with [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) and [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/):

```
db.getCollection("yourcollection").aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      sortNum: {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: ["$status", "published"] },
          0,
          { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$status", "draft"] }, 1, 2] }
        ]
      }
    }
  },

  {
    $sort: {
      sortNum: 1
    }
  }
]);
```

**OR** With [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
      sortNum: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {
                $eq: ["$status", "published"]
              },
              then: 1
            },
            {
              case: {
                $eq: ["$status", "delete"]
              },
              then: 2
            },
            {
              case: {
                $eq: ["$status", "draft"]
              },
              then: 3
            }
          ],
          default: 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      sortNum: 1
    }
  }]);
```